# Why can superusers run more simultaneous processes than unprivileged users?

Tags: c, unix, minix

*(Note: The program mentioned was written for a class assignment, but this question is not part of the assignment; it is for my own curiosity and I cannot find an answer elsewhere.)*

For a class assignment, I needed to write a program to determine the number of simultaneous processes that could be run by a user at once. My program creates a certain number of processes before `fork()` returns -1 because the limit has been reached, then it terminates those processes and ends.

When I run as `root`, it counts 16 created processes before terminating them, which makes sense. The Minix 2 [man page for `fork()`](http://minix1.woodhull.com/current/2.0.4/wwwman/man2/fork.2.html) specifies that the limit is set by the `NR_PROCS` variable in `/usr/include/minix/config.h`, and that is set to 32. `root` is running 16 processes in addition to the 14 created by the program (+2 for shell and the program itself), so that makes a total of 32 processes.

When I run as the unprivileged user `ast`, however, the program only returns 13 (so it's only spawning 11 processes plus the two for shell and program). I'm using `su ast` to run as the `ast` user, but I don't know if that process is taken into account. **UPDATE:** Logging in as `ast` causes the program to spawn 12 processes, so adding the two for shell and the program itself means `ast` can only have 14 simultaneous processes running (the user is not running any others).

Why is there a difference in the number of processes that can be run by superusers and unprivileged users, especially when only one variable controls the system limit?

Comment: Yes, `su ast` is one process and then it forks a shell for `ast`, that's another process. What happens if you login as `ast`  and run?

Comment: @Blue Moon I considered doing that but login as `ast` is disabled (the entry in `/etc/passwd` gives `*` in the place where the password would be written, which means it is invalid). I'll give it a try tomorrow when I have a bit more time to mess around on the system; most of tonight consisted of actually writing the program.

Comment: @BlueMoon I enabled login as the `ast` user and ran the program; it reported 14 processes. `ast` is only running one other process, `-sh`, and that's accounted for in the program, so it looks like the `ast` user can actually only spawn 14 processes at once compared to `root`'s 32, assuming my code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a user's process limit protects the system by ensuring that a mis-use or malicious use (like a [fork bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb)) by a user cannot completely break the system (in theory, at least).  Root processes can continue to start and run.

Sometimes this is a per-user setting (to protect other users) and sometimes it is a user/root split (to protect the system) and sometimes it is both.